# How to include python-dateutil in Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

How can I use the `python-dateutil` library in Google App Engine? I am using the `webapp2` framework and need to know how to include the library and use it in my script.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT2:  Here's the recommended way to do this now: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27#vendoring

<s>EDIT: Thanks to @TimHoffman, the correct (App Engine) way to do this is documented [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appengineconfig#Configuring_Your_Own_Modules). Ignore what I said below.</s>

I've actually had to do this exact thing. First, I created a folder in my app project called 'lib' to hold any python libraries that aren't included with App Engine (for project organization). Then, I downloaded the dateutil python source and placed it in the new 'lib' folder. Finally, in your actual app code, before importing the desired libraries, you must add this line:

```
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'lib'))
```

which just places the 'lib' folder in the python path so that python knows where the module actually is. Then simply:

```
import dateutil
```

Alternatively, you could just put the module code directly in your app folder, and python will automatically look in your program's folder for the module. Also, make sure it's included somewhere in your app.yaml so that it actually gets uploaded to google's servers.

The key, though, is that you must include the code for the module somewhere with your app.

Comment: Notice that, as written, the 'lib' folder must be in the same folder as the script being run.

Comment: or use the tool gaenv i built for this: http://blog.altlimit.com/2013/06/google-app-engine-virtualenv-tool-that.html - echo "python-dateutil" > requirements.txt, pip install -r requirements.txt then gaenv, it automates this answer. ohh and install it pip install gaenv

Comment: sys.path modifications are best done in appengine_config.py which is loaded before any of your code.  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appengineconfig

Comment: Thank you am heading somewhere with it

Comment: am getting this error now OSError: [Errno 38] Function not implemented

Comment: De docs have changed, since the link in this answer doesn't mention a lib folder at all...

Comment: @Jaap The last sentence of my 'EDIT' says to ignore the rest of my answer after the edit including what I said about a lib folder. Follow the link and use those instructions instead.

Comment: @Jaap Sorry - it's been a reeeeally long time since I've use AppEngine. I've updated my answer with the Google recommended way to add third party modules.